# Change color slash " / " breadcrumb

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image]

How to change the slash color " / " in breadcrumb. I've tried to add color in css, there is no change

```html
<ol class="breadcrumb" style="font-size: 20px;">
   <li class="breadcrumb-item" href="/homepage/index.html">
      Home
   </li>
   <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      Package
   </li>
   <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <span class="text-danger">Nusa Penida</span>
   </li>
</ol>
```

```css
.section-details-header{
  min-height: 43px;
  background: ; 
  margin-top: -45px;
}

.section-details-content{
  color:#ffffff;
}
.breadcrumb{
  color:#fff;
 text-align: center;
 justify-content: right;
}
```

Comment: css error on `background: ;`....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: is ti bulma framework?

Comment: @MisterJojo i use bootstrap

Comment: Why don't you  correct this line with no value ?  ` background: ;` ?

Comment: @MisterJojo cause in design figma is blank, i forgot to delete that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/` characters are actually `::before` pseudo-elements; use that to re-stylize them:

```css
.breadcrumb > li + li::before {
  color: #f00 !important;
}
```

Try it:

```css
.breadcrumb > li + li::before {
  color: #f00 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item">Level 1</li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item">Level 2</li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Level 3</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<ol class="breadcrumb" style="font-size: 20px;">
    <li class="breadcrumb-itemsection-details-header" href="/homepage/index.html">
      Home <span style='color:red'>/</span>
    </li>
   <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      Package <span style='color:red'>/</span>
   </li>
   <li class="breadcrumb-item">
      <span class="text-danger">Nusa Penida</span>
   </li>
</ol>
```

use style or class in same or new li tag with slash.

Comment: Bootstrap breadcrumbs already contain the slashes, there is no need to add them manually.